# jQuery Tabs & CSS Style

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Tabs to style part of my page.

I originally had the page like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Part 1</legend>

    ...
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Part 2</legend>

    ...
</fieldset>
```

I then put these two items inside a tab control:

```
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#tab1">Part 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab2">Part 2</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div id="tab1">
       <fieldset ...>
   </div>

   <div id="tab2">
       <fieldset ...>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs();
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that after I did this the tab control has modified the style of the fieldsets within it. Everything within the tabs has a larger font size, etc.

How can I easily say that everything in tab1 & tab2 should not be affected by the style of the tab control?

I want the tab control itself to have the larger font size and font, but the children should keep the old font size and font family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from JQuery IU itself. namely `ui-widget`.

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkTfu)

There are 2 ways around this, remove the offending css yourself like the example.

Or add a css style to target fieldset when they are within the class `ui-widget`